# Unknown reason for "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index" exception

Tags: list, user-interface, unity-game-engine, exception, button

I am making a Unity game where the player is collecting data about aliens.
Therefor the player points on the alien and uses something like a camera.

Camera --> shoots Ray --> Ray returns all needed data attached to the script on the alien-gameobject

```
void ShootRay()
{
    RaycastHit hitInfo; // stores information about hitted object
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxRaycastRange, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("creature"))) // out hitInfo = Unity puts information in the variable hitInfo
    { 
        // UI alerts and collecting dna
        if (hitInfo.distance <= photoRaycastRange) 
        {

            distanceInfo.text = "scanning_genome";


            if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI> ().dna_collected == false) {

                if (dna_percent_0_to_1 < 1) 
                {
                    calming_dna_scan_circle = false;
                    distanceInfo.text = "scanning_genome";
                    dna_percent_0_to_1 += Time.deltaTime * dna_scanSpeed;
                    dna_collect_circle.fillAmount = dna_percent_0_to_1;
                } 
                else if (dna_percent_0_to_1 >= 1) 
                {

                    // adding info of creature to database
                    if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyAI> ().raceIndex == 1) 
                    {
                        if (!raceOneWasAdded) 
                        {
                            BestiariumData.scannedSpecies.Add (hitInfo.collider.gameObject);
                            raceOneWasAdded = true;
                        }
                        BestiariumData.dnaBar_1 += 0.25f;
```

The mentioned database is simply a class called BestiariumData with:

```
public static List<GameObject> scannedSpecies = new List<GameObject> ();

public static List<float> savedDNAFillRates = new List<float> ();

public static float dnaBar_1 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_2 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_3 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_4 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_5 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_6 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_7 = 0;
public static float dnaBar_8 = 0;
```

}

I'm having a menu where the player can check which aliens he/she already has collected data. The name of the alien is displayed (Monster One, ...) and a progress bar for how many alien individuals the player has scanned.

[image: Menu with Name of Alien (monster one, monster two...) and a bar that shows how much of all alien individuals the player has scanned]

**THE PROBLEM:**
if I try to assign the NAME of the status bar if throws the **ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index** exception. I am doing this by setting a bool in another script to true.

```
public List<GameObject> monsterButtons = new List<GameObject>();
public static bool nameButtons = false;


// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () 
{
    if (nameButtons) 
    {
        for (int buttonIndex = monsterButtons.Count; buttonIndex > 0; buttonIndex--) 
        {
            monsterButtons [buttonIndex].GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = BestiariumData.scannedSpecies [buttonIndex].name;
        }

    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Button index gives the count of your list. So say your list contains 10 items, count will be 10.
However a list's index starts at 0, not 1.

So when you try to access monsterButtons [buttonIndex] for the first time, you are calling index 10, which means item 11. This does not exist so throws your error.

To fix, add "-1" to your index asigning:

```
for (int buttonIndex = monsterButtons.Count -1; buttonIndex >= 0; buttonIndex--) 
    {
        monsterButtons [buttonIndex].GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = BestiariumData.scannedSpecies [buttonIndex].name;
    }
```

Comment: You also need to access the '0th' element so you need to use buttonIndex >= 0.

Comment: @ryeMoss I was about to edit that into the answer too but then saw your Edit.